# Podio API item revision difference doesn't return external_id for changed fields [UPDATE: fixed!]

Tags: podio

[EDITED TO ADD: The API is now fixed and returns the `external_id` as expected]

The Podio API that returns the diff between one revision of an item and another is documented [here](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374)

The diff that is returned by the API contains an array of changed fields. For each field we can see the `field_id` and the `label` but not the field's `external_id`.

Is this a bug in the API? The [official Ruby gem](https://github.com/podio/podio-rb/blob/master/lib/podio/models/item_diff.rb#L14) for this API has a property `external_id` that is never populated.

Is there a way of getting the field's `external_id` without making further (rate-limited) API calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Podio API has now been updated to include the `external_id` of the field.

Just for the record, the Podio dev team implemented and released this fix within 24 hours of understanding the problem. Yay them!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported use case because there will never be an `external_id` on an `item_diff`.

The library will be corrected.

See github conversation [1]

[1] https://github.com/podio/podio-rb/issues/39

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, if you read the question carefully you'll see I'm asking about the `external_id` for each field in the diff, not for the diff itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change of fields, changes the external IDs, so this call doesn't return external ID. If you want "external_id" of the changed field, you can make a api call "Get item" and get it.

Comment: Changing the `label` might change the `external_id`, but that would be an app level change and would not affect item revisions.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this incorrect answer, please can you provide a comment to say why you did so?

Answer (score 0):

the PHP PodioItemDiff::get_for() version doenst return external_id